# how to feed suds with an already xml-formated request message

Tags: python, testing, soap, suds

I have some webservice to test, running on a server, in axis2.

I have been given some xml data that we should receive from third parties using our webservice. that xml data is well formatted according to the wsdl of our webservice.

so as to test i do: *(following the axis2.py test file given in suds)*

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/{0}?wsdl'.format('myWebService')
print 'url=%s' % url
client = Client(url)
print client
with open("input.xml") as f:
    inputXml = f.read()
print client.service.myWebserviceRequest(inputXml)
```

and i get the following error message:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made becau
se the target machine actively refused it>
```

as far as I see with the statement `print Client`, it's that suds is awaiting objects not under the xml form, but under python form. ( that's what the rest of the axis.py code suggest)

but in my case I have the data already formated in xml. Do you know how I could input it directly as xml into the request `client.service.myWebserviceRequest` ?

(it is not a problem of connection since I access to the axis2 webservice `getVersion`)

**EDIT1:** output of the `print client statement`.

```
Service ( myWebService ) tns="ws.myCompany.com"
   Prefixes (2)
      ns2 = "myData.ws.myCompany.com"
      ns3 = "ws.myCompany.com"
   Ports (1):
      (MyServiceSSOAP12port_http)
         Methods (1):
            sendMyInformation(ns2:DATA_HEADER DATA_HEADER, ns2:OTHER_CONTENT OTHER_CONTENT, )
         Types (1):
            WSExceptionType
```

What puzzles me is that the suds Client expose a  service of the form `sendMyInformation((ns2:DATA_HEADER DATA_HEADER, ns2:OTHER_CONTENT OTHER_CONTENT,)`

whereas in my wsdl the data to supply is:

```
<xs:element name="WHOLE_CONTENT">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="DATA_HEADER"/>
            <xs:element ref="OTHER_CONTENT"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `print client`?

Comment: I have edited and added the info.

Comment: You should call `client.service.sendMyInformation` instead of `client.service.myWebserviceRequest`. But Suds expect a `DATA_HEADER` and a `OTHER_CONTENT` object, not your `inputXml`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just saw this question when looking for answers,

have you solved it?. are you looking something like the below

MESSAGE INJECTION (Diagnostics/Testing?)¶
The service API provides for message/reply injection.

To inject either a soap message to be sent or to inject a reply or fault to be processed as if returned by the soap server, simply specify the __inject keyword argument.

when invoking the service. Eg:

Sending a raw soap message:

`print client.service.test(__inject={'msg':message})`

GP

Answer (score 1):

Starting with I think suds version 0.39, you can pass in the raw xm you want to send over.

```
from suds.sax.text import Raw

xml = Raw('<person name="jeff"><age>5</age></person>')
result = client.service.sendMyInformation(xml)
```

To inspect what is actually been sent, when constructing the client you cant set a nosend flag to true. This flag doesn't send but generates the soap

```
client=Client(url, nosend=True)
print client.envelope
```